# Always boot into Ubuntu, but with Windows option on restart

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I'm not sure if this is possible - I've tried searching, but can't seem to find anything. I run a dual boot system, Trusty & Win 7 - being in the former about 98% of the time.

Here's what I'd like: always boot into Ubuntu, but have the option from within Ubuntu of rebooting into Win 7 - with subsequent boots going back to Ubuntu.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just try pressing shift key as BIOS is loading. You will get grub options. You can choose your os.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to have this an automatic process instead of manual - hence the desire to bypass grub.

Comment: That can be done. By editing root/etc/default/grub file.

Comment: I do not know if this still works or not. `sudo grub-reboot 1` where number is entry you want. Note count starts at 0. Or: `sudo grub-reboot "Microsoft Windows 7"` Note that title must match entry in menu exactly.